# Some properties not visible in SP Search on newly added user

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, people-search

Running sp2013 onpremise

We have added a new user to our AD and runned UPS AD sync. I can see the users email and phone on:

- her mysite
- in SharePoint (through powershell EnsureUser().Email)
- In UPS-->Manage user properties

But when I go to search center page and search for her name, I get a hit but her email and phone number does not show up.

I have a used custom display template 
Existing users works fine, I can see their mail and phone no

Comment: Sometimes it helps, when the user visit her mysite by herself. 
Try also running full crawl.

Comment: user has been visiting and full crawl is done nightly (propblem occured a few days ago)

Comment: Are the user profiles on a different content source with a different crawl schedule?

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for your reply. No, they are all(sites and users) on same content source.